# Simple form in rails doesn't display validation error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form

I have this `simple_form` in my app but it doesn't display any validation error messages:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>

     <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input :first_name, label: "Prénom" %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, label: "Nom" %>
    <%= f.input :email, label:"email" %>
    <%= f.input :telephone, label: "telephone"%>

    <p><%= f.label :birthdate, 'Date de naissance' %></p>
    <%= f.date_select :birthdate, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil, :use_month_names => ['Janv.','Fevr.', 'Mars', 'Avr.', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil.', 'Août','Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Déc.'], :order => [:day, :month, :year], :start_year => 1910, :end_year => 1995} %>
     <%= f.input :genre, label: "Sexe" %>
    <%= f.input :ranking, label:"Classement" %>
    <%= f.input :licence_number, label: "numéro de licence"%>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :Photo%>
      <%= f.file_field :picture %>
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :licence %>
    <%= f.file_field :licencepicture %>
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :certificat %>
    <%= f.file_field :certifmedpicture %>
    </p>
    <div id="validation"><%= f.submit %></div>
    <% end %>
```

Here are my validations in my user model

```
 validates :first_name, presence: { strict: true }, on: :update
 validates :last_name, presence: { strict: true }, on: :update
```

and you can have a look at my `simple_form.en.yml`:

```
en:
simple_form:
"yes": 'Yes'
"no": 'No'
required:
  text: 'required'
  mark: '*'
  # You can uncomment the line below if you need to overwrite the whole required html.
  # When using html, text and mark won't be used.
  # html: '<abbr title="required">*</abbr>'
error_notification:
  default_message: "Certains champs posent problèmes:"
```

My `update` method:

```
def update
  @user.update(user_params)
  @user.create_mangopay_natural_user_and_wallet
  redirect_to user_path(current_user)
end
```

I don't get why the error notifications don't display as I have the proper `f.error_notification` in my view

Comment: Are you checking for errors correctly in the controller?

Comment: Try `<%= simple_form_for(@user), :validate => true do |f| %>`.

Comment: @sjagr I thought that was native to simple_form. How would I do that ? Here's my update method:

    `def update
       @user.update(user_params)
       @user.create_mangopay_natural_user_and_wallet
       redirect_to user_path(current_user)
     end`

Comment: @sprungl Assuming that OP has installed [`client_side_validations-simple_form`](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form), right?

Answer (score 1):

As revealed in your comments, your controller doesn't check for a successful save and just blindly redirects to the user page. I didn't see any native functionality from `simple_form` that does this for you. You need to check for this successful save and re-render the edit form on failure so it can show those errors in `f.error_notification`:

```
def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    @user.create_mangopay_natural_user_and_wallet
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry but it still doesnt work... When I try to submit a form without a first name I get ActiveModel::StrictValidationFailed at /users/5
it doesnt display the error message (the else part is not executed)